# oAuth2.0 with Microsoft flow(Power Automate) and then accessing protected API

Tags: azure-active-directory, power-automate, azure-authentication

I'm working on setting up a Microsoft flow that will need to access a registered web app, which utilizes oAuth2 authentication. The purpose of this would be to obtain a JWT access token that will be used to access the protected API in the web app. I don't have a lot of experience with Microsoft Flow so I'm wondering how one would login through Auth2 with Username/Password and retrieve the token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use "HTTP" connector to get the access token and use this token to request your app. Please refer to the steps below:

1. You need to know this OAuth2.0 flow to request an access token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

For this step, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), and I think you have already known how to get the access token by OAuth 2.0 resource owner password credentials grant in postman.

2. Then we can do this operation(get the access token) in Microsoft Flow(power-automate).
   [image]

Please replace the {tenantId} and xxxxx above with your own information.

3. After running this Microsoft flow, we can get the access token successfully.
   [image]
4. If you want to use this access token in the following actions in your Microsoft flow, you can use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the response body from the HTTP action and then use the access token(shown as below screenshot)
   [image]

Comment: thank you so much for your response! I'm always grateful for your help. I've tried this, and it appears to have hit the authentication. I do have 2-factor authentication and it seems to be complaining about that. 

"error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access ....
  "error_codes": [
    50079
  ]

Is this something flow can handle?

Comment: I opted to do this with Http with Azure AD. For the base and resource URL, I'm using my web app's application ID. This prompted me to login, and I was able to do so successfully. When I performed a GET request to the API, I got an error code 302: Redirect with the location "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...."

Despite logging in, it appears that my API is unauthenticated. Do I need to make this call using a bearer token, and if so how would I extract this token from the previous login?

Comment: Hi @vfirma For your first question, I think you can try to grant the permission to your application. Please go to the app(which you request for an access token) in your azure ad and click "API permissions" tag --> "Add a permission", then choose "My APIs" tag. Then select the permission under your web app, add it. After a few minutes, please click the "Grant admin consent for *" button.

Comment: @vfirma For your second question, I will try to help you in your another post.

Comment: I'm new to all of this so I'm so grateful for your help. I'm unable to modify the API permissions now since I don't have authority. I will ask my boss to try this change first thing tomorrow. If you have any other suggestions, I might be able to try a few other things now.

One thing I'm still very confused about is why my API calls still require logging in. When using connector Http with Azure AD, I'm required to log in. Why are my API calls unauthenticated despite the login via connection? Can I extract the access token to use as a bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using custom connectors. If you don't have 2FA setup on your account, Hury's answer works just as well.

Comment: Hi @vfirma, Would you please elaborate your answer on explaining what exactly you implemented inside the custom connector to solve the 2FA challenge ?